# Settings File VS 2008 escapes c# carraige return

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to persist the C# carraige return (\r\n) directive in a app settings file.
The designer however is escaping the sequence to (\r\n) , a behaviour I don't want.

I have manually modified the default value attritube in the settings.designer file ,but this only works for the life time of the application and then reverts to the escaped sequence.

Is there any way to store the literal in the settings file?

Comment: I do john , my apologies

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an easy way to do that in VS directly. You can write the text in notepad with actual newline characters and copy & paste it to the field in the designer.